# Placing application files in bin folder

Tags: java, file, file-io

How can I place the files being used by my application, more particularly text files that contains data that my Java program uses. For the images since it is static, I just copy and paste them in the bin folder. But I have some text files that I create during runtime and I don't know where to place them. I need a place where I can save them in and edit them sometime.

By the way, I am using eclipse IDE.

And how would I code it? Like retrieving etc.
I am reading files with Scanner, creates them with Formatter

Answer (score 0):

If you using Eclipse IDE you can just place the text files in the source folder and eclipse will copy them to the bin folder when building the application. When editing the files in the source folder within Eclipse it will update the copy in the bin folder. When you edited them with an external program you need too choose the “Refresh” menu item in the Eclipse IDE.

Place them relative to the .java file of the class using them so that the copy in the bin folder will be relative to the .class file as well. The you can access them via `MyClass.class.getResourceAsStream("path relative to MyClass.class");` which gives you an input stream. This works even if you package your application as a JAR file.

Comment: Note: this is read-only, for files modified by your application the bin folder is not the right place. For such resources, simply implement using a folder the user can configure.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I need a location where I my application can modify the file. like the highscores in a game application, and I don't want the user to get access to it. Only my program can access

Comment: Use the Preferences API. This will store inside the Registry on Windows. There is no way to hide something to an experienced user though. You could encrypt the data but since the user has access to your program (s)he can find the key in your program anyway. So it’s all about your effort to raise the effort the user would have trying to manipulate it.

Comment: @krato `Preferences` API works in Linux as well as Windows. In Linux, it will be stored in user home directory. You can specify the location manually.

Comment: The Preferences API is platform independent but the backend storage will be platform dependent. In other words, under Linux, for example, there is no Registry therefore the Preferences implementation will store your data in XML files in a special folder. So you don’t have to worry about how it will store the data but you cannot assume the data to be hidden to the user on all platforms. But as already said you cannot hide the data to an experienced user anyway.